# Can't connect app server to MySQL database in a docker network

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker

I cannot get my spring-boot server to run against my database using docker.

If I start up my mysql database (called **shape-shop-db-container**) and intialize the database like so :

```
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 --name=shape-shop-db-container --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root" --env="MYSQL_PASSWORD=root" --env="MYSQL_DATABASE=shapeshop" mysql
docker exec -i shape-shop-db-container mysql -uroot -proot shapeshop < SCHEMA.sql
docker exec -i shape-shop-db-container mysql -uroot -proot shapeshop < TEST_DATA.sql
```

and then run my application server *within* my IDE with the following **application.properties** :

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shapeshop?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

server.port=8080
```

everything works *fine*.

Now

.... instead of running my application server through my IDE, I instead have it running on a docker *container*, and I try the following :

(1) create network 'shape-shop-network'

```
docker network create shape-shop-network
```

(2) run db container as before, but this time specifying the *network* as well.

```
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 --name=shape-shop-db-container --network shape-shop-network --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root" --env="MYSQL_PASSWORD=root" --env="MYSQL_DATABASE=shapeshop" mysql
docker exec -i shape-shop-db-container mysql -uroot -proot shapeshop < SCHEMA.sql
docker exec -i shape-shop-db-container mysql -uroot -proot shapeshop < TEST_DATA.sql
```

(3) now i build my app server and run it on a container called 'shape-shop-server'.

```
docker build -t shapeshop:1.0 .
docker run --name shape-shop-server -p 8080:8080 shapeshop:1.0 --name shape-shop-server --network shape-shop-network
```

But when I run it in the container, I get "unable to acquire JDBC Connection" error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
2022-11-03T11:34:10.043594500Z  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:275) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
2022-11-03T11:34:10.043602700Z  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
2022-11-03T11:34:10.043610900Z 

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:na]
```

Why is this happening? Is something 'off' with my ports? Why would it work in my IDE but not as a container? I would assume that the settings are the same.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to rename "localhost" in my **application.properties** to shape-shop-db-conatiner. Eg :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://shape-shop-db-container:3306/shapeshop?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
```

But I get "Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: shape-shop-db-container" , even though **shape-shop-db-container** is running.

Comment: I think there should be an underlying exception that tells you the root cause of not being able to create the JDBC connection.

Comment: yes, updated my question with a underlying exception

Comment: ...i am thinking I need to replace "localhost" in my applicatino.properties with something else but i am not sure what

Comment: why dont you use docker compose? and send us docker-compose.yml? because otherwise, It will be very hard for us to know all the docker dynamics (aka configuration)

Comment: Yeah, connection refused indicates that you are connecting to the wrong host or port. If you try to connect from the app docker instance to a localhost mysql, then mysql instance should be in the same docker instance as your application. My understanding is that this is not the case.

Comment: yeah, i might try to do it with docker-compose. But I wanted to do it more "close to the bone" so I could learn mroe about docker

Comment: I'd suggest to inspect content of `/etc/hosts` file and execute `env` command within `shape-shop-server` container. AFAIR Docker injects information about other containers there (but, perhaps, it doesn't do it now and you might have to specify deprecated `--link` option for that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to establish a connection with another Docker container within a network, its hostname should be used instead of its name. By default, the container’s hostname is set to the container’s ID, which can be overridden using the `--hostname` flag with `docker run` command.

Another option would be to use the `--network-alias` flag, also with `docker run` command, to specify network-scoped alias for a container, which can be used as an alternative to a hostname. Likewise, the alias can be specified with the `--alias` flag when connecting to an existing network using `docker network connect` command.

Consider using `docker-compose` where you don't have to worry about network and hostnames.

For reference: [Container Networking](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#ip-address-and-hostname) and [Docker run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)

Answer (score 1):

The hostname for the docker container is not the same as "name".

You should apply the --hostname parameter when starting the docker container to specificy the hostname it would be given.
You can then use that to connect to it from another container in the same network.

Answer (score 0):

try change jdbc:mysql://shape-shop-db-container:3306 to jdbc:mysql://host_ip_address:3306